# before_action logs out user post update (using devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to restrict access to the user edit page so that logged in user can only edit his/her own profile.  FYI, I'm using Devise for user authentication, login, register, etc.  This is supposed to be pretty easy to do with

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Profile Updated!'
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    # code left out... but pretty self explanatory right?
  end

  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user == find_user
  end
end
```

The weird thing is, when I have the before_action :correct_user, when the user updates... it logs the user out post-update!  When I don't have the before_action :correct_user, it leaves the user logged in and redirects to edit page of the user.  I tried manually signing the user in def update prior to redirecting to edit page, but it does not work.  In fact, that isn't even the issue.  When I compare the current_user and User.find(params[:id]), the current_user is logged in!  But for some reason, having the before_action :correct_user there logs me out!

I've been banging my head on the wall for quite some time on this one.  Can anyone help out?  This is a Rails 4 app and am using the latest version of devise.

Thank you!

Comment: Personally, I would avoid the entire situation and just make the User resource a singular one in your routes. Avoid the whole lookup situation and just have all the actions act on the current_user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really need the `find_user` method here.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def update
    current_user.update_attributes user_params
    respond_with current_user, location: [:edit, current_user]
  end

  private
  def user_params
    ...
  end
end
```

Seeing as you only let a user edit their own record, you can just use `current_user` in the `update` method.

Also, if you are happy to use the standard Rails convention for CRUD operations, then `respond_to/with` will save you a little time and code by implementing that for you. I used the `location` option otherwise `respond_with` defaults to the `show` page of the resource.

Comment: Find user is for eliminating duplicate code.  It's not necessary, but I think it's nice.  I tried updating with current_user, but it still signs out :(

Comment: You don't need to do the `before_action :correct_user` if you're using `current_user`.